# RecyclerView Effect Selected items in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Programming Language : KOTLIN

Library: androidX

I am using a RecyclerView, from the AndroidX Library, in Kotlin and one problem occurred.

Problem: When I clicked on the first showing item, then more items get affected, always after 10 items.

Example: If first item is clicked then items 1, 11, 21,31 will be affected too.

here is code

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.jdwebservices.mybigbachat.R
import com.jdwebservices.mybigbachat.data.products
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.product_row.view.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class product_adapter(var contet:Context, var catlist: ArrayList<products>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val v:View=LayoutInflater.from(contet).inflate(R.layout.product_row,parent,false)
        return clientHolders(v)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return catlist.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { }
         (holder as clientHolders).bind(
           catlist[position].product_name_app_english,
           catlist[position].product_image,
           catlist[position].mrp,
           catlist[position].sale_rate,
             position
       )
    }

    class clientHolders(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val BASE_URL = "https://mybachatbasket.xyz/"
        var counter = -1
        fun bind(
            product_name_app_english: String,
            product_image: String,
            mrp: Int,
            sale_rate: Int,
            products: Int
        ) {
            if (counter == -1) {
                itemView.add_1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                itemView.add_to_cart.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            var pos = adapterPosition
            if(pos == products){
            itemView.product_name.text = product_name_app_english

            itemView.mrp_full.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            itemView.mrp.text = mrp.toString()
            itemView.sale_rate.text = sale_rate.toString()

            var eb: String = BASE_URL + "admin/resource/uploads/" + product_image
            eb = eb.replace(" ", "%20")
            Picasso.get().load(eb).into(itemView.product_image)

            itemView.add_1.setOnClickListener {

                counter = 1
                 Toast.makeText(itemView.context, pos.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               // Toast.makeText(itemView.context, products.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //  add_cart(product_id,category_id,counter)
if (pos >= 0) {
    itemView.add_1.visibility = View.GONE
    itemView.add_to_cart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    itemView.count.text = counter.toString()
}else{
    itemView.add_1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    itemView.add_to_cart.visibility = View.GONE

}

            }

            itemView.add.setOnClickListener {

                counter++
                itemView.count.text = counter.toString()

            }
            itemView.delete.setOnClickListener {

                counter--
                itemView.count.text = counter.toString()
                //  updtae_cart(last_id,counter);
                if (counter == 0) {
                    itemView.add_1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    itemView.add_to_cart.visibility = View.GONE
                }

            }

        }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Jashan Deep, Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add a Minimal code and problem statement? It will help some of us to better understand your problem.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584141/recyclerview-ambiguos-setvisibility-function-clicking-on-one-view-affects-multi

Comment: Please add some code snippet from your view holder. My guess is that your binding is wrong, you are missing the basic information about the recyclerview and how it works.

Comment: You need to use adapterPosition instead of position, but make sure to check != - 1

Answer (score 1):

The `recyclerview` recycles the view in `OnBindViewHolder`.So when items are clicked it gets reflected in some other positions.

For better understanding about selection state of `recyclerview` see [this example](https://demonuts.com/recyclerview-checkbox/)

In your `model` class add an extra property named `isSelected` with `getter` and `setter` like

```
public class YourModel{
    // your other properties

    private boolean isSelected;

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

And in your adapter, you have to set `isSelected` is `true` if user click on the item otherwise it will be false inside your `onBindViewHolder()`. here is an example below

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.checkBox.setText("Checkbox " + position);

        // here you can check is this item clicked or not 
        if(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getSelected()){
           holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        holder.tvAnimal.setText(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getAnimal());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer pos = (Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getAnimal() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (imageModelArrayList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                    imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    imageModelArrayList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Hope it helps you.